# How do I use mathmode in tables to write physics formulae?

Tags: tables, math-mode

I am trying to create a table in which I want to write a couple of physics formulae but I am getting a ton of errors and Google isn't helping. My code looks like this:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
Drehmoment               & $ M = l\cdot F $                                  \\
Leistung                 & $ P = Ne\cdot \rho\n^{3}\cdot d_{R}^{5} $         \\
                         & $ P=M\cdot \omega=M\cdot 2\pi \cdot n $           \\
Newtonzahl               & $ Ne=\frac{P}{n^{2}\cdot d_{R}^{5}\cdot \rho} $   \\
                         & $ Ne=f(Re) $                                      \\
Reynoldszahl             & $ Re=\frac{n\cdotd_{R}^{2} \cdot \rho}{\eta} $    \\
Mischzeit                & $ t_{m}=t_{e}-t_{a} $                             \\
Dimensionslose Mischzeit & $ T_{M}=t_{m}\cdot n $                            \\                     
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `\n` is not defined (perhaps you mean it to be `n` or `_n`), and you probably mean `\cdotd` to be `\cdot d`.  Fix those two items and it compiles.

Comment: None of the errors I get when running your code are related to using math mode in a table, they're related to typos in the math code that @StevenB.Segletes has correctly identified. Remember next time to include the error messages, doing so would have enabled us to instantly see where the problem was and we can then explain the errors to you. Also, it's good to include a full Minimal Working Example (MWE) [link](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Including a basic preamble and a `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` really helps

Comment: Thanks alot, they were typos and i kept wondering what i was doing wrong.

Comment: Your clue is in the error message, when LaTeX prints the error message it breaks a line after the undefined control sequence. Sometimes the real cause of the error is actually some time before LaTeX runs into problems, which can mask things, but in this case, the error message correctly identifies `\n` as the problem

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as stated in the comments, the problem was a few typos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, `\n` is not a defined LaTeX macro.  I am assuming it was a typo intended as `_n`.  Also, `\cdotd` should be `\cdot d`, as appears earlier in your example.

As an aside, I used `\dfrac` (from the `amsmath` package) and `\arraystretch` to make it look better (to my point of view).  Also, heeding egreg's suggestion, `\mathit{Nu}` and `\mathit{Re}` have been employed.

In the following MWE, I perform the result twice, the first time using `tabular` and the second time, using `array` (and `tabularx` package), as suggested by Au101.  The output is the same, but one input syntax may be preferable to the other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\label{my-label}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
Drehmoment               & $ M = l\cdot F $                                  \\
Leistung                 & $ P = \mathit{Ne}\cdot \rho_n^{3}\cdot d_{R}^{5} $         \\
                         & $ P=M\cdot \omega=M\cdot 2\pi \cdot n $           \\
Newtonzahl               & $ \mathit{Ne}=\dfrac{P}{n^{2}\cdot d_{R}^{5}\cdot \rho} $   \\
                         & $ \mathit{Ne}=f(\mathit{Re}) $                                      \\
Reynoldszahl             & $ \mathit{Re}=\dfrac{n\cdot d_{R}^{2} \cdot \rho}{\eta} $    \\
Mischzeit                & $ t_{m}=t_{e}-t_{a} $                             \\
Dimensionslose Mischzeit & $ T_{M}=t_{m}\cdot n $                            \\                     
\end{tabular}

\[
\begin{array}{>{$}l<{$}r}
Drehmoment               &  M = l\cdot F                                   \\
Leistung                 &  P = \mathit{Ne}\cdot \rho_n^{3}\cdot d_{R}^{5}          \\
                         &  P=M\cdot \omega=M\cdot 2\pi \cdot n            \\
Newtonzahl               &  \mathit{Ne}=\dfrac{P}{n^{2}\cdot d_{R}^{5}\cdot \rho}    \\
                         &  \mathit{Ne}=f(\mathit{Re})                                       \\
Reynoldszahl             &  \mathit{Re}=\dfrac{n\cdot d_{R}^{2} \cdot \rho}{\eta}     \\
Mischzeit                &  t_{m}=t_{e}-t_{a}                              \\
Dimensionslose Mischzeit &  T_{M}=t_{m}\cdot n                             \\                     
\end{array}
\]
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer. It might benefit the OP to mention the `array` package and `>{$}r<{$}`. Also, is it worth considering `Ne` ---> `\mathit{Ne}` (also for `Re` although the output happens to look much more acceptable in this particular case)

Comment: Wow this is amazing, i wasn't expecting so much help this fast :-D is there a way to show appreciation on this site other than commenting?

Comment: @Nyx you can click the up-arrow to the left of my answer to "upvote" an answer that is helpful, and for questions that you ask, you can click the check mark to **one** of the (possibly many) answers you receive, to indicate the answer that best solves your problem.

Comment: @Nyx Yes!! In fact, commenting is not encouraged for that purpose. Next to this answer is a tick, you can click it and it will go green. This accepts the answer and awards the answerer 15 points (and you 2), although you have to wait a bit. When you earn a few more rep points, you can also upvote (with the arrows), giving the answerer 10 rep points and it adds one to the answer score.

Comment: You don't need to use an `array` environment to use the `>` and `<` syntax from the `array` package. `\begin{tabular}{l>{$}r<{$}} ... \end{tabular}` will work just as well

Comment: @Au101 True enough, but you mentioned `array` and I thought it might open new vistas for the OP, who may be unaware of its existence.

Comment: FWIW, what's needed for the power formula in the second row is to replace `\rho\n^3` with `\rho\cdot n^3`... (I.e., the OP had somehow failed to type "cdot" after `\rho\`.)

Answer (score 5):

My mathematician's eyes bleed when seeing all those `\cdot` symbols. `;-)`

A couple of suggestions: define macros for the Newton and Reynolds numbers, that replace `\mathit{Ne}` and `\mathit{Re}`. When such a symbol is preceded or followed by another factor, separate them with `\,`.

With `booktabs` and a “phantom” trick you can achieve equal height for all rows. I'd much prefer left alignment for the formulas.

A table should have its caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\newcommand{\NZ}{\mathit{Ne}} % Newton number
\newcommand{\RZ}{\mathit{Re}} % Reynolds number

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Physikalische Formeln\label{my-label}}

\begin{tabular}{l >{$}l<{\vphantom{\dfrac{R^2}{y}}$}}
\toprule
Drehmoment               & M = l F                               \\
Leistung                 & P = \NZ\, \rho_n^{3} d_{R}^{5}        \\
                         & P = M \omega = 2\pi M n               \\
Newtonzahl               & \NZ = \dfrac{P}{n^{2} d_{R}^{5} \rho} \\
                         & \NZ = f(\RZ)                          \\
Reynoldszahl             & \RZ =\dfrac{n d_{R}^{2} \rho}{\eta}   \\
Mischzeit                & t_{m}=t_{e}-t_{a}                     \\
Dimensionslose Mischzeit & T_{M}=t_{m} n                         \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Like I commented under Steven's answer, I think the [power formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_number) ("Leistung" is German for "power") in the second row should read `Ne \rho n^3 d^5_R`...

Comment: @Mico Possibly so. I'll leave that as an exercise. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg With \phantom, the tabuler is wider than the original one. How do you explain this difference?

Comment: @pzorba75 `\phantom` also reserves the horizontal space

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of variety, here's still another suggestion for how you might typeset the table. In particular, I suggest separating the symbol and the defining formula (formulae in two cases) in separate columns. I further suggest that you right-align rather than left-align the text column and left-align the material in the third column.

Finally, I also suggest fine-tuning the appearance of the `d_R` term, specifically, snugging up the `R` to the `d` via a `\!` (negative thinspace) directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}}
% Macros for typesetting "Ne" and "Re" in upright Roman (math) font
\newcommand\Ne{\mathrm{Ne}}
\renewcommand\Re{\mathrm{Re}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rCL}
Drehmoment            & M  & l\cdot F            \\
Leistung              & P  & \Ne\cdot \rho \cdot n^{3}\cdot d_{\!R}^{5} \\
                      &    & M \cdot \omega=M\cdot 2\pi \cdot n         \\[1ex]
Newtonzahl            &\Ne & \frac{P}{n^{2}\cdot d_{\!R}^{5}\cdot \rho} \\[1ex]
                      &    & f(\Re)                                     \\[1ex]
Reynoldszahl          &\Re & \frac{n\cdot d_{\!R}^{2} \cdot \rho}{\eta} \\[1ex]
Mischzeit             &t_m & t_{e}-t_{a}         \\
Dimensionslose Mischzeit & T_{M} & t_{m}\cdot n  \\                     
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose 4 variants, one based on `tabular, the others oan`align`or`alignat`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, x11names]{article}
\usepackage{array, empheq}
\usepackage[vmargin = 2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
  \label{my-label}
  \begin{tabular}{l>{$\displaystyle}r<{$}}
    Drehmoment & M = l · F \\
    Leistung & P = Ne · ρn^{3} · d_{R}^{5} \\
                             & P=M · \omega=M · 2π · n \\
    Newtonzahl & Ne=\frac{P}{n^{2} · d_{R}^{5} · ρ} \\
                             & Ne=f(Re) \\
    Reynoldszahl & Re=\frac{n · d_{R}^{2} · ρ}{η} \\
    Mischzeit & t_{m}=tₑ-t_{a} \\
    Dimensionslose Mischzeit & T_{M}=t_{m} · n \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{align*}
    & \text{Drehmoment} & M & = l · F \\
    & \text{Leistung} & P & = Ne · ρn^{3} · d_{R}^{5} \\
    & & P & =M · \omega=M · 2π · n \\
    & \text{Newtonzahl} & Ne & =\frac{P}{n^{2} · d_{R}^{5} · ρ} \\
    & & Ne & =f(Re) \\
    & \text{Reynoldszahl} & Re & =\frac{n · d_{R}^{2} · ρ}{η} \\
    & \text{Mischzeit} & t_{m} & =tₑ-t_{a} \\
    & \text{Dimensionslose Mischzeit} & T_{M} & =t_{m} · n \\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    & \text{Drehmoment} & & M = l · F \\
    & \text{Leistung} & & P = Ne · ρn^{3} · d_{R}^{5} \\
    & & & P=M · \omega=M · 2π · n \\
    & \text{Newtonzahl} & & Ne =\frac{P}{n^{2} · d_{R}^{5} · ρ} \\
    & & & Ne=f(Re) \\
    & \text{Reynoldszahl} & & Re =\frac{n · d_{R}^{2} · ρ}{η} \\
    & \text{Mischzeit} & & t_{m} =tₑ-t_{a} \\
    & \text{Dimensionslose Mischzeit} & & T_{M} =t_{m} · n \\
\end{align*}

\begin{empheq}[box =\setlength\fboxsep{10pt} \fbox]{alignat* = 2, }
  \text{Drehmoment} & & & M = l · F \\
  \text{Leistung} & & & P = Ne · ρn^{3} · d_{R}^{5} \\
                                  & & & P=M · \omega=M · 2π · n \\
  \text{Newtonzahl} & & & Ne =\frac{P}{n^{2} · d_{R}^{5} · ρ} \\
                                  & & & Ne=f(Re) \\
  \text{Reynoldszahl} & & & Re =\frac{n · d_{R}^{2} · ρ}{η} \\
  \text{Mischzeit} & & & t_{m} =tₑ-t_{a} \\
  \text{Dimensionslose Mischzeit} & & \qquad & T_{M} =t_{m} · n \end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: +1. I happen to like the fourth approach the best. :-) However, I'd probably reduce the distance between the text and the formulae somewhat. Also, "Reynoldszahl" appears to be aligned differently from the other chunks of text.

Comment: Thanks, @Mico. I did reduce the distance to 2em. As to the alignment of ‘Reynoldszahl’, there was a spurious space at the end. Fixed.